Menu Scroll Down Issue in WordPress
I am managing a WordPress websit. I am facing issues with the menu settings for which I do not have a solution.
There are many options added to the menu, but when I hover the mouse over the menu, the dropdown does not show the entire menu. I want to add a scroll down option to this menu.
My knowledge of WordPress is at a beginner level, so I need help.
How and where to add a code for enabling the scroll down option is menu section?

There was no screenshot

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

As I can check from the website it looks like you are referring to the sub-menu which has more items not showing on the front-end.
To fix this issue you need to add the given CSS to Appearance > Customizer > Additional CSS.


@media only screen and (min-width: 981px) {
    .primary-menu-menu ul.sub-menu{
        max-height: 80vh;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
}



Once you add the code it will show like this.
Screenshot : https://ibb.co/GCCKrVk

Yes, it's working, thanks a lot for the help, highly appreciated. :) But, now another issue has occurred. Subpages in the menu are not showing up. :(
